# Tensorflow cond doesn't stop gradient on the false branch

Tags: tensorflow

I am building a RNN model, where the init_state could come from one of two cases. 1) a static init_state that is fed in via feed_dict, from the previous time-step output state. 2) some function of a variable, which I call score.

```
init_state = cell.zero_state(batch,tf.float32)
with tf.name_scope('hidden1'):
     weights_h1 = tf.Variable(
                        tf.truncated_normal([T, cells_dim],
                        stddev=1.0 / np.sqrt(T)),
                        name='weights')
     biases_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([cells_dim]),
                        name='biases')
     hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(score, weights_h1) + biases_h1)

init_state2 = tf.cond(is_start, lambda: hidden1, lambda: init_state)
```

init_state2 is then used as input to static_rnn, which eventually is used to calculate loss and train_op. I would expect the train_op to have no impact on weights_h1 when is_start is False. However, the weight changes after each updates. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lazy evaluation only applies to tensors constructed during `tf.cond` invocation. The way you constructed your graph means all tensors are evaluated regardless of value of `is_start`

Comment: I tried to put everything within tf.name_scope('hidden1') inside a python function MLP() and change the middle lambda to MLP. It throws a error "Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("X:0", shape=(20, 100), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph." However, this changes does not impact X at all. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def return_init_state():
    init_state = cell.zero_state(batch,tf.float32)
    return init_state

def return_hidden_1():
    with tf.name_scope('hidden1'):
        weights_h1 = tf.Variable(
                            tf.truncated_normal([T, cells_dim],
                            stddev=1.0 / np.sqrt(T)),
                            name='weights')
        biases_h1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([cells_dim]),
                            name='biases')
        hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(score, weights_h1) + biases_h1)

        return hidden1

init_state2 = tf.cond(is_start, lambda: return_hidden_1, lambda: return_init_state)
```

Notice how the methods are called within the context of `tf.cond`. Therefore, whatever op is created, will be within the context of `tf.cond`. Otherwise, in your case, the ops will run either ways.

Comment: I'm also confused. I understand that in the forward branch both branches are evaluated if they are not constructed in the context of tf.cond, but before. What I don't understand is that the gradient on the false branch is not 0 during back propagation. The gradient should only propagate into the true branch (as it does in the tf.max function as well, doesn't it?)